# Android - Creating a graph from data of an xml file and saving it as a .png

Tags: android, xml, graph, png

I need to retrieve some information from an xml file and make a graph with this information and then save the graph as an image before displaying it on my device.

Any suggestion on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GraphViz which takes a graph as input and produces a graphical rendition of it (e.g. in SVG); and at DotML which is an XML vocabulary for describing the graphs which you can input to GraphViz. So basically you transform your XML into DotML, submit it to GraphViz, and get SVG out, which you can then display.